# postgresql column names as variable in a subquery

Tags: postgresql

```
    table1
    id col1 col2 col3...

    table2
    col_id col_name
    3432 col1
    5342 col2
    6756 col3
```

Now I want to generate table 3 like this:
id col_name col_value col_id

Please note that col1, col2,col3... are not in order. Therefore I have to query table2 to obtain col_id ( I think pivot does not work here)

How can I do it in SQL?

Comment: Pretty unclear, what's what in this question. Please present a clear question.

Comment: sorry. a typo. should generate table 3. corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want a select like this:

```
SELECT t2.id, 
   CASE 
     WHEN t2.col_name='col1' THEN t1.col1 
     WHEN t2.col_name='col2' THEN t1.col2
     WHEN t2.col_name='col2' THEN t1.col2 
     -- ... more columns
     ELSE NULL
   END
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table2 t1 ON t2.col_id = t1.id
```

You could also create a function, though this will be slower in practice:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table1_col(id integer, name text) RETURNS text as $$
DECLARE
   col_val text;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT %s FROM table1 WHERE id=$1', name) 
     INTO col_val
     USING id;
   RETURN col_val;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT table1_col(col_id,col_name) FROM table2;
```

Comment: yeah. but  table1 has hundreds of columns. Am I suppose to type hundreds of lines for "when"? I am a developer but not db admin. Maybe I can output the table and write python to do this.

Comment: Using a script to generate repetitive SQL is entirely appropriate. I added an example of a function to pull the value of the column by name. It would be interesting to benchmarks between a long CASE WHEN vs the function call -- but with a separate query being planned and executed for each row, it's almost certainly slower.